# How to Prepare Chickpea Purée from a Can?

Tags: chickpeas

I got a can of "chickpea purée with sesame paste" (though the English name on the can seems to be "chickpeas with sesame purée"), produced by Baktat, as a gift. It is [this product](http://www.baktat.com.tr/en/search.php?search=8690804692215&submit=Search).

The can specifies the ingredients in various languages, but fails to provide any preparation instructions. **How can I prepare it?**

Do I have to cook it, or fry it (as is possible with potato purée)? For how long exactly/until what state is reached? Do I have to add anything, or will it dissolve in water? Can I microwave it instead?

*There are loads of online recipes to create your own chickpea purée, but that's not what I'm looking for; I'm looking for preparation instructions specifically for the indicated (or a comparable) product.*

Comment: "Chickpea puree with sesame paste" sounds like hummus. Are you sure you need to do anything to it? I'd think you could just eat it.

Comment: @sourd'oh: Yes, the can also says "Humus". I don't know - I just assumed that it's not eaten cold, or is it?

Comment: Yes, it's usually served as a dip

Comment: @sourd'oh: Hm, a quick Google search brings up many results such as [Cold Hummus Is A Crime No One Should Commit](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/05/12/cold-hummus-ruins-everything_n_5295733.html) or [Hummus should NOT be eaten cold](http://www.dnaindia.com/lifestyle/report-hummus-should-not-be-eaten-cold-1993886), but also some that express differing opinions.

Comment: Like a lot of foods, there are many strong opinions. While I'd agree that's it's better warm, you definitely *can* eat it cold.

Comment: @sourd'oh: Ok, but then, *how* do I warm it up? My naive imagination is that if I put it into a pot *without* water, it will quickly burn and stick, whereas if I put it into a pot *with* water, it will simply dissolve into some "thick soup". Hence my question. Can I microwave it, or will that ruin it in some other, unforeseen way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18917/discussion-between-sourdoh-and-o-r-mapper).

Comment: This question is way too easy to be understood as a request for recipes with hummus, which would be off topic. I protected it so new users won't start posting these.

Comment: Normally hommus would be made fresh for the meal.   One would keep the court bouillon from the chickpeas them as you pound/blend them with the garlic and tahini would would add the still warm stock to achieve the desired consistency.  This Would produce the afore mentioned warm dip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chickpea puree with sesame paste would be hummus. Hummus can be served warm or cold, so you could serve it straight out of the can if you wanted. To warm it up, I'd avoid heating it with any kind of direct heat, but it should be fine microwaved briefly. When it is served warm, it's not hot by any means, so a gentle heating is all that's needed.